# Python, suds, manage array answer

Tags: python, arrays, web-services, soap, suds

I'm using suds library to fetch a list of products from a webservice.

This is a sample code:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'WSDLURL'
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.Research('value')
```

Result contains:

```
(ArrayOfProducts){
   Product[] = 
      (Product){
         Id = 218
         Code = "C024"
         Name = "test2"
         Avaiable = True
         UrlDownload = None
         MetaData = 
            (ArrayOfMetaData){
               MetaData[] = 
                  (MetaData){
                     CoderepositoryISO = "16701"
                     Title = "1ST"
                  },
            }
      },
      (Product){
         Id = 219
         Code = "C025"
         Name = "test3"
         Avaiable = True
         UrlDownload = None
         MetaData = 
            (ArrayOfMetaData){
               MetaData[] = 
                  (MetaData){
                     CoderepositoryISO = "16702"
                     Title = "2ND"
                  },
            }
      },
...
```

There is a way, in python or suds, to access directly to the contained data cycling on the products with a for? (e.g.: Product.Id, Product.Code, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the format code button above the edit-field to format you code.

Comment: Also, please give an example of how you want your list (I suppose you meant list and not array) to look.

Comment: Does `for p in result.ArrayOfProducts: print p.Name` work?

Answer (score 5):

Perfect... Thanks to J.F. Sebastian I find the right way...
This is the working code:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'wsdl'
client = Client(url)
html_out = ""
result = client.service.Research('a')
for p in result.Product:
   print p.Id
   print p.Name
```

Comment: You could mark the answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer http://stackoverflow.com/faq